# Rails cron with whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I don't understand why "whenever" does not work

Schedule.rb

```
every 2.minutes do
  runner "Ping.check_pings"
end
```

Ping.rb

```
class Ping < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :LAN, :WAN, :info, :infastructure_id

    def self.check_pings      
      @monitor_ping = Ping.new()    
      @monitor_ping.WAN = "true"
      @monitor_ping.save 
    end
end
```

crontab -l

```
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/ruben/Monitoring && script/rails runner -e production '\''Ping.check_pings'\'''
```

rails runner "Ping.check_pings"
==> Works in command line

I tried it with my project running in "rails s" and without
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: By the way: To call a cron job every 2 minutes you can just use `*/2 * * * * ...`

Answer (score 4):

I am just guessing, but... Are you testing on development or production?.

If your are in development, don't forget to put on your schedule.rb:

```
set :environment, 'development'
```

Also you can do this:

```
every 10.minutes do
  runner "User.vote", environment => "development"
end
```

Regards
Ivan

Comment: I'm trying what you suggest but still getting -e production. I updated the crontab. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
'cd /home/ruben/Monitoring && script/rails runner -e production '\''Ping.check_pings'\'''
```

I think the character escaping is incorrect on this string; look at the `production '\''` piece, the first `'` closes the string, then you're escaping a `'` without a string being open. Try this:

```
'cd /home/ruben/Monitoring && script/rails runner -e production \'Ping.check_pings\''
```

or this:

```
"cd /home/ruben/Monitoring && script/rails runner -e production 'Ping.check_pings'"
```

or this:

```
'cd /home/ruben/Monitoring && script/rails runner -e production Ping.check_pings'
```

(you might not need quotes around the single shell-word at all. :)

Comment: I tried them all but non worked ): I would have foun it strange is that was the problem because the cron is auto generated by "whenever". Is there a possibility to force the crons so i can see if they throw an error or something?

Comment: @Nostrodamus, if cron is running, it'll run every two minutes, at least that part is right. :) You could use `echo date > /tmp/test` as the command if you wanted. (Edit your existing crontab with `crontab -e` to make the change.)

Comment: That works, every 2mins the test file gets modified. Nothing wrong with my cron. Can it be a permissions issue?

Comment: @Nostrodamus, possibly, if something like AppArmor, SELinux, TOMOYO, or SMACK is confining what gets run out of cron. But if you can run it from your shell, it ought to run from your crontab too, as confining cron isn't all that common.